# How did Latin's inchoative verb endings (-sco) get very productive in the Romance languages?

Tags: language-evolution, vulgar-latin, romance-languages

How did this particular suffix scheme get so common in the daughter Romance languages?
Take Latin: finire, finio
Then look at Spanish: fenecer, fenezco
Italian: finire, finisco
French: finir, je finis
Catalan: finir, fineixo

This different form is what got us the word, finish, with that -ish ending. We have other words like it: perish (pereo + sco) with a similar background.
What originally meant 'coming to an end', simply meant to end. Was it simply easier to conjugate (similar to the fate of frequentative -to forms)?